# How can I search of my favorites bar in IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am using Windows 7.
Is there a way to search on my favorites in IE 10, specially in the Favorites bar?

I tried different things but I couldn't find any window that let you search.

The Organize Favorites only allows you to add/rename/move/remove folders and items.

Comment: Hopefully helpful http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/search-your-internet-explorer-favorites-from-within-ie-in-vista-or-xp/

Comment: @Dave - Thanks, can't use add-ons. However it made me remember I can search on the file system, kinda sad I have to do it that way, though.

Comment: @Dzyann: Yes, that's one advantage (or maybe the opposite depending on how you look at it!) of the way IE does things. Favorites are simple .URL text files and not stored in any DB.